# How do I read a filepath from a text file using Python?

Tags: python, string, windows, path

I am currently trying to write a simple python script that opens a folder or a list of folders using filepaths that I have written down on my text file.

```
import os

with open('filepaths.txt') as f:
    [os.startfile(line) for line in f.readlines()]
```

My issue is that whenever I run this code, python reads the lines as its non-raw form. The backslashes are doubled, and there is a new line "\n" in every string.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:\\Nitro\\Downloads\n'
```

I have attempted to solve this problem using repr() on the variable. Instead of removing the backslash, it was doubled even further.

```
import os

with open('filepaths.txt') as f:
    [os.startfile(repr(line)) for line in f.readlines()]
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: "'D:\\\\Nitro\\\\Downloads\\n'"
```

I have also attempted to use the string replace function to replace "\" with "". It did not work.

Comment: show some lines of filepaths.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readlines` method reads the file correctly, with the trailing newline character in each line preserved. You just need to strip the newline character from the string before using it as a path name, which is typically done with the `str.rstrip` method:

```
for line in f: # no need to use the readlines method for iteration
    os.startfile(line.rstrip())
```

The path name in the error message you included in the question contains double backslashes because it is displayed with the `repr` function, with backslashes escaped already, not because the path names are read incorrectly.